# Why can't I make a WebRequest to a secondary domain from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, security

I have an 3rd Party API I'm wanting to use from my Silverlight 4 Application.  It's interface is simply a web request (NOT A WEB SERVICE!) with form variables. According to everything I've read, this is not possible because of security issues?  What security issues?  Is there no way to do this?  I can understand not allowing this with web services, but with simple web requests?

I cannot use my RIA Services gateway because the data is VERY sensitive and I cannot (and do not want to) transmit it under my own SSL cert.  This is RIDICULOUS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (XSRF). Without this measure, what's to stop an attacker from issuing requests to online banking sites (or any site) on the users behalf? Exploiting the fact he may have cookies stored which will allow the request to go through.

It's too bad the internet has turned into an assumed guilty until proven innocent situation, as I could see many useful, non-malicious, uses for sending web requests.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. I was thinking of the Silverlight application almost as if it were a downloaded client, but its not.  The user hasn't willingly downloaded it, as far as he or she knows its a web site. No?

Comment: @Jorday, yes, exactly. XSRFs could also be used to make users click ads, register users on sites, pretty much do anything web form based without the user knowing it is even taking place. You may be able to get around this silverlight security feature if your website is placed in their 'trusted sites' or is over an intranet, which is implicitly trusted.

Answer (score 4):

The same security issues apply in Adobe Flash. In JavaScript, it's not possible at all.

For Silverlight, the website root must contain a clientaccesspolicy.xml permitting the call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I still do not understand why this is a security threat? What could possibly happen that would harm the user of the Silverlight Application or the other domain?